# How can I access a Restful webservice using servlet?  

Tags: java, web-services, servlets

Is there any way I can access RESTful webservice using a servlet. I dont want to use Jersey client?
  **EDIT:** How can I pass object in the url and make sure that marshalling/unmarshalling is done properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could code your own HTTP requests e.g. using [HTTPURLConnection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).  Here you can set the request method and change the URL or/and body as appropiate e.g.

```
   URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/resource");
   HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
  // etc
```

This way you're just using the standard `java.net` API.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the commons-httpclient library (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) to make a request to your REST service, and gson (http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to serialize/deserialize java objects to JSON

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use jersey client, it's just a URL, you can use:

```
new URL("http://locationofservice").openConnection();
```